# Where do I place the MySQL C++ Connector files on Mac?

Tags: c++, mysql, macos

I am trying to install the MySQL C++ Connector on my Mac.  I downloaded the tar.gz file from mysql.com, and when I unzip it, I have three text files, one of which is a Readme that doesn't provide much help.  Then there is the  /include folder which has two C++ header files and then a sub-folder called /cppconn that has another 14 C++ header file.  Then there is also the other folder call /lib that contains a Dynamic Library file and two symbolic links to that Dynamic Library file, as well a a .a file.  I was wondering where I place these files or folders on my Mac so that I can write a C++ application that can connect to a database? Or if there is a way for gcc or g++ to be able see these files in a location I specify when compiling?  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know mac specifics, but usually (in linux / unix / windows - I dont expect mac to be any different) you either

- put the header files into some place that is in your compilers header path(such as /usr/include), library files in your compilers lib path (such as /usr/lib),

or

- you put them anywhere you like (perhaps /usr/local/my_cpp_connector) and then add that path to your compilers search path, both for headers and libraries.

You could also do like

```
/usr/local/my_cpp_connector/include
/usr/local/my_cpp_connector/lib
```

but I guess you got the idea at this point.